# node.js automatic logging with metadata

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I want to create a Node.js logged decorator (function filter) that works like this (pseudocode warning):

```
logged = function(f) {
    return function() {
        log(f.file, f.line, f.class, f.name, arguments)

        return f.call(this, arguments)
    }
}
```

Is there a way of accesing the information above? I'm going to be doing heavy logging, so throwing a fake `Exception` and reading the trace is probably not viable (or is it?).

*Note: by `f.class` I mean the name of the function that holds the `prototype`. Also, I'm using `coffee-script`, in case it matters*

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to `throw` the exception, `var stack = new Error().stack` is enough. From there it is possible to parse out the file, line number, and the class name. **BUT** the problem is, that it only tracks the function calls, so now to get the proper information for the decorated function `Error` should be initialized some where within the function or the class. Doing this in decorator, you can get only the information about the file/linenumber where the decoration of the function was occurred, and not where the function was declared.

```
function User(){}
User.prototype.foo = function(){};
User.stack_ = function(){
    return new Error().stack
};
// ...
function wrapp(Ctor, name){
    var stack = Ctor.stack_();
    var info  = parseStack(stack);
    var orig_ = Ctor.prototype[name];

    Ctor.prototype[name] = function(){
        console.log('Info:', info);
        return orig_.apply(this, arguments);
    };
}
function parseStack(stack){
    // implement better stacktrace parser
    return stack.split('\n')[1];
}
// ...
wrapp(User, 'foo');
// ...
var user = new User;
user.foo();
// and you get smth. like
// Info: at Function.User.stack_ (filename:line:column)
```

I think this is maximum you can get, and you must always define this `stack_` function.